# Rewrite loop using apply

Tags: r

Newbie question: This double loop on a data.frame of about 50K elements evaluates *very* slowly, taking over 30 seconds. I've read online that I should be using some form of the  apply function to fix this but so far cannot get the code right. Starting with a first data.frame that has gain results in it, the goal is to get a second data.frame where only the values greater than the target are filled in and all others have 0.

This code works:

```
ExcessGain = function(Value, Target){
  max(0,Value - Target)
}

Pcnt_O_O_x = data.frame()

for (j in 1:ncol(Pcnt_O_O)){
  for (i in 1:nrow(Pcnt_O_O)){
    Pcnt_O_O_x[i,j] = ExcessGain(Pcnt_O_O[i,j], GainTargetPcnt)
  }
}
```

Can I speed this up somehow using an apply function instead of the inside loop?

Comment: Are all values in the data.frame numeric?

Comment: Use `apply( Pcnt_0_0 , 1:2 , ExcessGain , GainTargetPcnt )` to apply your function to each cell in the array. *Should* work through positional matching of the arguments.

Comment: James - yes, at this time it's all numeric and could probably be faster using a matrix. Thanks

Comment: SimonO101 - I don't know how to paste code into this comment and have it be readable, but I replaced both loops with your apply and got the error message: > Pcnt_O_O_x = apply(Pcnt_0_0 , 1:2 , ExcessGain , GainTargetPcnt )
Error in apply(Pcnt_0_0, 1:2, ExcessGain, GainTargetPcnt) : 
  object 'Pcnt_0_0' not found

Comment: @LGTrader check out my answer below. Don't use loops, it looks like there is no need here. You should use what I have written below, but convert your `data.frame` to a matrix first using `as.matrix( mydataframe)` as it will work *very* quickly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function looks like it is just subtracting a target value from the value of each cell in your array. Any negative values are replace by 0. In that case you don't need any loops, you can just use R 's built in vectorisation to do this:

```
set.seed(123)
# If you have a data.frame of all numeric elements turn it into a matrix first
df <- as.matrix( data.frame( matrix( runif(25) , nrow = 5 ) ) )

target <- 0.5
df
#        X1        X2        X3         X4        X5
#1 0.2875775 0.0455565 0.9568333 0.89982497 0.8895393
#2 0.7883051 0.5281055 0.4533342 0.24608773 0.6928034
#3 0.4089769 0.8924190 0.6775706 0.04205953 0.6405068
#4 0.8830174 0.5514350 0.5726334 0.32792072 0.9942698
#5 0.9404673 0.4566147 0.1029247 0.95450365 0.6557058

df2 <- df - target
df2
#          X1          X2          X3         X4        X5
#1 -0.21242248 -0.45444350  0.45683335  0.3998250 0.3895393
#2  0.28830514  0.02810549 -0.04666584 -0.2539123 0.1928034
#3 -0.09102308  0.39241904  0.17757064 -0.4579405 0.1405068
#4  0.38301740  0.05143501  0.07263340 -0.1720793 0.4942698
#5  0.44046728 -0.04338526 -0.39707532  0.4545036 0.1557058

df2[ df2 < 0 ] <- 0
df2
#        X1         X2        X3        X4        X5
#1 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.4568333 0.3998250 0.3895393
#2 0.2883051 0.02810549 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1928034
#3 0.0000000 0.39241904 0.1775706 0.0000000 0.1405068
#4 0.3830174 0.05143501 0.0726334 0.0000000 0.4942698
#5 0.4404673 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.4545036 0.1557058
```

Here is some benchmarking to show the difference in speed in operating on a `matrix` as opposed to operating on a `data.frame`. `f.df( df )` and `f.m( m )` are two functions operating on a data.frame and matrix with 1 million elements resepctively:

```
require( microbenchmark )
microbenchmark( f.df( df ) , f.m( m ) , times = 10L )

#Unit: milliseconds
#     expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
# f.df(df) 6944.09808 9009.39684 9233.18528 9533.75089 10036.5963    10
#   f.m(m)   37.26433   39.00189   40.46229   41.15626   130.6983    10
```

Operating on a matrix is *two orders* of magnitude quicker when the matrix is big.

If you *really* need to use an apply function, you can aplpy to every cell of an matrix like so:

```
m <- matrix( runif(25) , nrow = 5 )
target <- 0.5
apply( m , 1:2 , function(x) max(x - target , 0 ) )
#         [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 0.4575807 0.0000000 0.15935928 0.0000000 0.1948637
#[2,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#[3,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#[4,] 0.3912719 0.0000000 0.06155316 0.1533290 0.0000000
#[5,] 0.3228921 0.4697041 0.23554353 0.1352888 0.0000000
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that if everything is numeric, using a matrix rather than a data frame will also be faster.

Comment: @joran yes, true thanks. I will edit that in. Maybe I make a *bigmatrix* and run some microbenchmarks?!! :-)

Comment: Simon - In this case you are correct, but in most cases I need to run more complex functions and would like to learn how to use some form of apply to do that. Thanks.

Comment: @LGTrader give an example function. It might be that the function can still be run vectorised. I will add the code for apply so you have it too.

Comment: @joran added some timing, Interestingly the number of columns seems to affect the benchmark time of data.frames, but not matrices (I guess matrices are really vectors and data.frames are really lists, and there must be some overhead accessing different elements (the columns) of a list?)

Comment: I added a question to ask this because I find it quite interesting that there should be such a speed difference in data.frames with equal number of elements but different number of columns

Comment: @Simon - I'm stumped. Your example runs perfectly but when I add it to my large program I get this error:> m <- matrix(Pcnt_O_O)
> target <- 3
> apply( m , 1:2 , function(x) max(x - target , 0 ) )
Error in x - target : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: @SimonO101 - I'm going to look into rewriting the program using matrixes for everything vs data.frames. As a newbie I like data.frames in RStudio because I can see them with View(df) and they look like an array. matrixes don't do that but I need to get past that bias and learn to do this right. Thanks

Comment: @LGTrader Try `as.matrix` not `matrix`, i.e. `m <- as.matrix(Pcnt_O_O)` it is different to what you wrote!

Comment: @SimonO101 - Sorry for the delay. YES! as.matrix seems to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonO101 - as an example of a function that seems hard to vectorize,  consider that the matrix is 5000x50 and I need to do a rolling correlation of column 5 with column 25 over the most recent 30 rows. (I.e. correlation on row 30 used data from rows 1:30, correltion on row 31 uses data from roaws 2:31, etc. I'm assuming something generically like apply(matrix1, function(x,y) cor(x,y,30)) could somehow be made to work but I'd be very happy to learn how to do it with vectorization if I can.

Comment: @LGTrader there is some good functions for that, but yes, you are better off using an `apply` and in this case probably using `rollapply`

Comment: @SimonO101 - Thanks. I've rewritten most of my code to use as.matrix and it is WAY faster. (10 seconds vs about 1 minute) I have one problem but I'll post that in a different question if I cannot figure it out myself. Much to learn.