# Speed of vectorized operation dependent of number of columns of data.frame

Tags: performance, r, dataframe, vectorization

Why does it take longer to operate a comparison on a data.frame with the same number of elements, but arranged in more columns on vectorized operations? Take this simple example, where we subtract 0.5 from each element and then compare it to see if it is < 0 ( [related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16218586/1478381) ):

```
f.df <- function( df , x = 0.5 ){
  df <- df - x
  df[ df < 0 ] <- 0
  return( df )
}


df1 <- data.frame( matrix( runif(1e5) , nrow = 1e2 ) )
df2 <- data.frame( matrix( runif(1e5) , nrow = 1e3 ) )
df3 <- data.frame( matrix( runif(1e5) , nrow = 1e4 ) )

require( microbenchmark )
microbenchmark( f.df( df1 ) , f.df( df2 ) , f.df( df3 ) , times = 10L )


#Unit: milliseconds
#     expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
# f.df(df1) 1562.66827 1568.21097 1595.07005 1674.91726 1680.90092    10
# f.df(df2)   95.77452   98.12557  101.31215  190.46906  198.23927    10
# f.df(df3)   16.25295   16.42373   16.74989   17.95621   18.69218    10
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit of profiling shows that most of your time is spent in `[<-.data.frame`.

The scaling issues therefore come from how `Ops.data.frame` and `[<-.dataframe` work and how   `[<-.data.frame` copies, and `[[<-` copies for a named list,.

The relevant code in  `Ops.data.frame` (with my comments)

```
 # cn is the names of your data.frame 
 for (j in seq_along(cn)) {
         left <- if (!lscalar) 
             e1[[j]]
         else e1
         right <- if (!rscalar) 
             e2[[j]]
         else e2
         value[[j]] <- eval(f)
     }
    # sometimes return a data.frame
     if (.Generic %in% c("+", "-", "*", "/", "%%", "%/%")) {
         names(value) <- cn
         data.frame(value, row.names = rn, check.names = FALSE, 
             check.rows = FALSE)
     } # sometimes return a matrix
     else matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), 
         nrow = nr, dimnames = list(rn, cn))
```

When you use `Ops.data.frame` it will cycle through your columns in the for loop using `[[<-` to replace each time.
This means as the number of columns increases, the time required will increase (as there will be some protective internal copying as it is a data.frame is named list ) -- hence it will scale linearly with the number of columns

```
# for example  only this part will scale with the number of columns
f.df.1 <- function( df , x = 0.5 ){
     df <- df - x

     return( df )
 }
microbenchmark(f.df.1(df1),f.df.1(df2),f.df.1(df3), times = 10L)
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr       min        lq   median         uq        max neval
# f.df.1(df1) 96.739646 97.143298 98.36253 172.937100 175.539239    10
# f.df.1(df2) 11.697373 11.955173 12.12206  12.304543 281.055865    10
# f.df.1(df3)  3.114089  3.149682  3.41174   3.575835   3.640467    10
```

`[<-.data.frame` has a similar loop through columns when `i` is a logical matrix of the same dimension as `x`

```
 if(is.logical(i) && is.matrix(i) && all(dim(i) == dim(x))) {
            nreplace <- sum(i, na.rm=TRUE)
            if(!nreplace) return(x) # nothing to replace
            ## allow replication of length(value) > 1 in 1.8.0
            N <- length(value)
            if(N > 1L && N < nreplace && (nreplace %% N) == 0L)
                value <- rep(value, length.out = nreplace)
            if(N > 1L && (length(value) != nreplace))
                stop("'value' is the wrong length")
            n <- 0L
            nv <- nrow(x)
            for(v in seq_len(dim(i)[2L])) {
                thisvar <- i[, v, drop = TRUE]
                nv <- sum(thisvar, na.rm = TRUE)
                if(nv) {
                    if(is.matrix(x[[v]]))
                        x[[v]][thisvar, ] <- if(N > 1L) value[n+seq_len(nv)] else value
                    else
                        x[[v]][thisvar] <- if(N > 1L) value[n+seq_len(nv)] else value
                }
                n <- n+nv
            }
            return(x)


f.df.2 <- function( df , x = 0.5 ){
     df[df < 0 ] <- 0

     return( df )
 }
 microbenchmark(f.df.2(df1), f.df.2(df2), f.df.2(df3), times = 10L)
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
# f.df.2(df1) 20.500873 20.575801 20.699469 20.993723 84.825607    10
# f.df.2(df2)  3.143228  3.149111  3.173265  3.353779  3.409068    10
# f.df.2(df3)  1.581727  1.634463  1.707337  1.876240  1.887746    10
```

---

`[<-` data.frame (and `<-`) will both copy as well

---

How to improve. You can use `lapply` or `set` from the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
sdf <- function(df, x = 0.5){
   # explicit copy so there are no changes to original
   dd <- copy(df)
  for(j in names(df)){
    set(dd, j= j, value = dd[[j]] - 0.5)
    # this is slow when (necessarily) done repeatedly perhaps this 
    # could come out of the loop and into a `lapply` or `vapply` statment
    whi <- which(dd[[j]] < 0 )
    if(length(whi)){
     set(dd, j= j, i = whi, value = 0.0)
    }
  }
  return(dd)
}

 microbenchmark(sdf(df1), sdf(df2), sdf(df3), times = 10L)
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq    median        uq        max neval
# sdf(df1) 87.471560 88.323686 89.880685 92.659141 153.218536    10
# sdf(df2)  6.235951  6.531192  6.630981  6.786801   7.230825    10
# sdf(df3)  2.631641  2.729612  2.775762  2.884807   2.970556    10

# a base R approach using lapply
ldf <- function(df, x = 0.5){

  as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(xx,x){ xxx <- xx-x;replace(xxx, xxx<0,0)}, x=x))

}

# pretty good. Does well with large data.frames
microbenchmark(ldf(df1), ldf(df2), ldf(df3), times = 10L)
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq    median         uq        max neval
# ldf(df1) 84.380144 84.659572 85.987488 159.928249 161.720599    10
# ldf(df2) 11.507918 11.793418 11.948194  12.175975  86.186517    10
# ldf(df3)  4.237206  4.368717  4.449018   4.627336   5.081222    10

# they all produce the same
dd <- sdf(df1)
ddf1 <- f.df(df1)
ldf1 <- ldf(df1)
identical(dd,ddf1)
## [1] TRUE
identical(ddf1, ldf1)
## [1] TRUE

# sdf and ldf comparable with lots of columns
# see benchmarking below.
microbenchmark(sdf(df1), ldf(df1), f.df(df1),  times = 10L)
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr        min         lq     median         uq       max neval
# sdf(df1)   85.75355   86.47659   86.76647   87.88829  172.0589    10
# ldf(df1)   84.73023   85.27622   85.61528  172.02897  356.4318    10
# f.df(df1) 3689.83135 3730.20084 3768.44067 3905.69565 3949.3532    10
# sdf ~ twice as fast with smaller data.frames
 microbenchmark(sdf(df2), ldf(df2), f.df(df2),  times = 10L)
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min         lq     median         uq        max neval
# sdf(df2)   6.46860   6.557955   6.603772   6.927785   7.019567    10
# ldf(df2)  12.26376  12.551905  12.576802  12.667775  12.982594    10
# f.df(df2) 268.42042 273.800762 278.435929 346.112355 503.551387    10
microbenchmark(sdf(df3), ldf(df3), f.df(df3),  times = 10L)
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
# sdf(df3)  2.538830  2.911310  3.020998  3.120961 74.980466    10
# ldf(df3)  4.698771  5.202121  5.272721  5.407351  5.424124    10
# f.df(df3) 17.819254 18.039089 18.158069 19.692038 90.620645    10

# copying of larger objects is slower, repeated calls to which are slow.

microbenchmark(copy(df1), copy(df2), copy(df3), times = 10L)
# Unit: microseconds
# expr     min      lq   median      uq     max neval
# copy(df1) 369.926 407.218 480.5710 527.229 618.698    10
# copy(df2) 165.402 224.626 279.5445 296.215 519.773    10
# copy(df3) 150.148 180.625 214.9140 276.035 467.972    10
```

Answer (score 7):

data.frames are lists: each column can hold data of a different class. So as you imagine, when you run your code, R has to treat each column separately. As a result, the "vectorization" only happens on a column basis. For the same number of elements in your data.frame, the more columns you have the longer they will take to process.

This is unlike matrices (more generally arrays) which only hold data of one class, so vectorization can happen throughout. Here, for the same number of elements, the computation time will be the same regardless of the number of columns. As you can see:

```
df1 <- matrix( runif(1e5) , nrow = 1e2 ) 
df2 <- matrix( runif(1e5) , nrow = 1e3 ) 
df3 <- matrix( runif(1e5) , nrow = 1e4 ) 

require( microbenchmark )
microbenchmark( f.df( df1 ) , f.df( df2 ) , f.df( df3 ) , times = 10L )

# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  f.df(df1) 4.837330 5.218258 5.350093 5.587897 7.081086    10
#  f.df(df2) 5.158825 5.313685 5.510549 5.731780 5.880861    10
#  f.df(df3) 5.237361 5.344613 5.399209 5.481276 5.940132    10
```

Answer (score 0):

when comparing `df1` to `df2` to `df3`:  by changing the number of rows yet holding the total number of elements constant you are consequently changing the number of columns.

each column in a `data.frame` is a list.   Each data.frame in your example has an order of magnitude more columns, hence and order of magnitude more operations, and thus time.

Comment: You have only described what is happening, not why. My question starts *Why does it take longer to operate a comparison on a data.frame with the same number of elements, but arranged in more columns*!! Each example has the same total number of elements.

Comment: you are confounding the number of *elements* with the number of *operations*.   in your function, the number of *operations* is a function of the number of columns.

Comment: I'm sorry but you will have to explain that. I am not applying a function across columns here. Are you telling that if I have a data.frame of 10 *elements* arranged across 2 columns (5 rows) and I subtract a number from each one, that I am somehow computing twice as many operations as if I did it with a dataframe with 10 elements arranged in one column (10 rows)?

Comment: Sorry if I sound rude, I appreciate you taking the time to answer. But how would it be different if I did `x <- seq(1:10) ; dim(x) <- c(5,2) ; x - 1` and  `x <- seq(1:10) ; dim(x) <- c(10,1) ; x - 1` same number of operations right in a different format?