# Fast way of converting large list to dataframe

Tags: r, performance, list, dataframe

I have a huge list (700 elements), each element being a vector of length = 16,000.
I am looking for an efficient way of converting the list to a dataframe, in the following fashion (this is just a mock example):

```
lst <- list(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6), c = c(7,8,9))
```

The end result I am looking for is:

```
 #  [,1] [,2] [,3]
 #a    1    2    3
 #b    4    5    6
 #c    7    8    9
```

This is what I have tried, but isn't working as I wish:

```
library(data.table)
result = rbindlist(Map(as.data.frame, lst))
```

Any suggestion? Please keep in mind that my real example has huge dimensions, and I would need a rather efficient way of doing this operation.

Thank you very much!

Comment: you really want them stacked like that and have 16k columns but only 700 rows?

Comment: Would it be better from some standpoint to have 700 columns and 16,000 rows instead?

Comment: most likely yes (e.g. here you could just do `as.data.frame(lst)` or `as.data.table(lst)`), but it depends of course on what you're going to do next (ime it would be extremely unusual to want that many columns)

Comment: Well, it is convenient for me to set the dataframe that way, but I guess I could do the opposite. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: There's a *big* difference between row-ordered and column-ordered.  My hoop-jumping below assumed that I wasn't allowed to change that part of the question ... oh well.

Comment: @Mariam definitely better to have more rows than columns, otherwise you spend a lot of time accessing the list elements. See [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16219708/1478381) of mine.

Comment: You can also use `ldply(k)` from `plyr` package

Comment: @Metrics: I haven't checked, but I would guess that `ldply` is not fast ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this.  We assume the components of `L` all are of the same length, `n`, and we also assume no row names:

```
L <- list(a = 1:4, b = 4:1) # test input

n <- length(L[[1]])
DF <- structure(L, row.names = c(NA, -n), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If list lacks names then use this: `structure(L, row.names = c(NA, -n), .Names = seq_along(L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: +1 cool trick. Does this do less copying than say `do.call`? It seems quite a bit faster.

Comment: I would assume that since its directly built up from its constituent parts that it would be fast.

Answer (score 6):

I think

```
lst <- list(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6), c = c(7,8,9))
do.call(rbind,lst)
```

works.  I don't know if there's a sneakier/dangerous/corner-cutting way to do it that's more efficient.

You could also try

```
m <- matrix(unlist(lst),byrow=TRUE,ncol=length(lst[[1]]))
rownames(m) <- names(lst)
as.data.frame(m)
```

... maybe it's faster?

You may not be able to do very much about speeding up the `as.data.frame` step.  Looking at `as.data.frame.matrix` to see what could be stripped to make it as bare-bones as possible, it seems that the crux is probably that the columns have to be copied into their own individual list elements:

```
for (i in ic) value[[i]] <- as.vector(x[, i])
```

You could try stripping down `as.data.frame.matrix` to see if you can speed it up, but I'm guessing that this operation is the bottleneck.  In order to get around it you have to find some faster way of mapping your data from a list of rows into a list of columns (perhaps an `Rcpp` solution??).

The other thing to consider is whether you really need a data frame -- if your data are of a homogeneous type, you could just keep the results as a matrix.  Matrix operations on big data are a lot faster anyway ...

Comment: It does work, but it is very slow in case of large lists (which is my situation here)

Comment: The `matrix()` takes a few minutes to complete, but I guess I could work with that in the meantime. Converting the matrix to a dataframe completely freezes the R GUI though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How about just `t(as.data.frame(List))` ?

```
> A = 1:16000
> List = list()
> for(i in 1:700) List[[i]] = A
> system.time(t(as.data.frame(List)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.25    0.00    0.25
```

Comment: I get a very odd result when I do that.. Although my initial list didnt' have names for elements, the dataframe now has some odd column names when I do `as.data.frame(List)`

Comment: That's because I didn't give my sample data any names.