# Combine Vectors inside of a List to Create a Dataframe R

Tags: r, list, vector, dataframe, rbind

I have a list of evenly sized characters vectors, and I wish to efficiently combine them into one dataframe, with the vectors in the list to become the rows of the new dataframe. In the following, `ls` is my list and `df` is my pre-allocated dataframe.

```
ls <- list(c("r1c1", "r1c2", "r1c3"),
           c("r2c1", "r2c2", "r2c3"))

df <- data.frame(col1 = character(), col2 = character(), col3 = character(),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

# Desired Result:
  col1   col2   col3
1  r1c1   r1c2   r1c3       
2  r2c1   r2c2   r2c3
```

As of now, I've tried `rbind(df, ls)` which seemingly creates the new dataframe by column, such that `df` looks like:

```
  c..r1c1....r1c2....r1c3.. c..r2c1....r2c2....r2c3..
4                      r1c1                      r2c1
5                      r1c2                      r2c2
6                      r1c3                      r2c3
```

I've also tried to perform the `rbind` inside of a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(ls))
  df <- rbind(df, ls[[i]])
```

This, however, gives me the warning message: `invalid factor level, NA generated`, even though I originally set `stringsAsFactors` to false. Rbind also seems to be a slow process when constantly performed on larger lists, so I would like to minimize its use if possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use

```
 data.frame(do.call(rbind, ls))
```

as a quick and simple way to turn your list of vectors into a matrix and then a data.frame

Comment: This will be pretty slow on anything remotely large. If you do `L <- do.call(Map,c(c,listname))` and then this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18748069/496803 it will be much quicker.