# Why is `sapply` much slower to process rows than columns in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

Consider the following script, which we will call `Foo.r`.

```
set.seed(1)                                       
x=matrix(rnorm(1000*1000),ncol=1000)              
x=data.frame(x)                                   


dummy = sapply(1:1000,function(i) sum(x[i,]) )    
#dummy = sapply(1:1000,function(i) sum(x[,i]) )
```

When the first `dummy` line is commented out, we are summing columns, and the code takes less than a second to run on my machine.

```
$ time Rscript Foo.r  

real    0m0.766s
user    0m0.536s
sys     0m0.080s
```

When the second `dummy` line is commented out (and the first is commented in), we are summing rows, and the run time is closer to 30 seconds.

```
$ time Rscript Foo.r  

real    0m30.589s
user    0m30.248s
sys     0m0.104s
```

Note that I am aware of the standard summing functions `rowSums` and `colSums`, but I am using sum only as an example for this strange asymmetric performance behavior.

Comment: you will find that if you use matrix instead of dataframes, the timings would be similar. I suppose the reason lies probably in the representation of columns in R. A dataframe is actually just a list of vectors.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't really the result of `sapply`, rather it has to do with how data frames are stored and the implications that has for extracting rows versus columns. Data frames are stored as lists, where each element of the list is a column.

This means that extracting columns is easier than extracting rows.

To demonstrate that this has nothing to do with `sapply`, consider this, using your data frame `x`:

```
foo1 <- function(){
+   for (i in 1:1000){
+       tmp <- x[i, ]
+   }
+ }  
> 
> foo2 <- function(){
+   for (i in 1:1000){
+       tmp <- x[ ,i]
+   }
+ }
> system.time(foo2())
   user  system elapsed 
  0.029   0.000   0.031 
> system.time(foo1())  
   user  system elapsed 
 15.986   0.074  15.894
```

If you need to do things row-wise and fast, data frames will often be a bad choice. To operate on rows, it has to extract corresponding elements from each list item. To operate on columns it only has to loop through the columns.

Comment: So what is it in `rowSums`/`rowMeans` that makes their efficiency on `data.frame`s very close to their column variants? On a 1000x1000 `matrix`, by the way, column operators are almost three times as fast, while on a 1000x1000 `data.frame` it was only about 1.1 times as fast.

Comment: @AnandaMahto The first line of code in `rowSums` is `if (is.data.frame(x)) x <- as.matrix(x)`.

Comment: @joran I think you need to explain a bit more clearly that a data.frame is a list of (column) vectors with a class attribute. E.g., you could show `unclass(x)`.

Comment: There is a great and detailed answer to a similar question I asked here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/16228567/1478381